# Ring of integers in $\mathbb{Q}(\omega_{p_1},\omega_{p_2},...,\omega_{p_n})$

Tags: commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

Let $p_k$ denotes the $k$'th prime and let $R_n$ be the ring of integers in $\mathbb{Q}(\omega_{p_1},\omega_{p_2},...,\omega_{p_n})$. Now let $R=\cup_{n=1}^{\infty} R_n$. Then is it true that $R_{\mathfrak p}$ is noetherian for every prime ideal $\mathfrak p$ in $R$ ?

Well here $R$ is nothing but integral closure of $\mathbb{Z}$ in $F=\mathbb{Q}(\omega_{p_1},\omega_{p_2},....)$. My motivation behind this question is that $F/\mathbb{Q}$ is an infinite extension. If it were finite that would become Dedekind and would force all of those localizations to be noetherian but here we're dealing with infinite extension and the ring is also pretty nice. That's why I'm interested in it.

Comment: I suppose that $\omega_p$ denotes a $p$th primitive root of unity, right?

Comment: Yes that's what I meant

Comment: Can you give some motivation for this problem, or any thoughts how to solve it? People tend to appreciate it here.

Comment: I've edited....

Comment: Shockingly, this is apparently true even though $R$ itself is not Noetherian (which isn't hard to see). This is true by work of Nakano. See example 2 here: http://www.math.ucla.edu/~rse/210c.1.08s/examples.pdf

Comment: I'm somewhat amazed that you asked this question. Did you really not know it's true? This fact (the fact that it is true) is apparently exceedingly deep, and specific to this very particular extension. It just seems so strange that one of the few fields that there answer is 'yes' to, you asked. What is, again, your motivation for this particular ring having this property?

Comment: @AlexYoucis $R_{\mathfrak{p}}$ means $R / \mathfrak{p}$ ?